# Tags [non-printable] and [non-printing-characters]

Tags: support, synonym-request

Tags [non-printable](/questions/tagged/non-printable) and [non-printing-characters](/questions/tagged/non-printing-characters) seem to be about the same thing.

Comment: What do you want done about it?

Comment: @Undo, it's a [tag:synonym-request].  Adrian, "Please e specific about which tag should be a synonym of which".

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think this comes down to a popularity contest.  Here are some statistics:

More users elected to tag [non-printable](/questions/tagged/non-printable), that users are most likely to attempt that tag.  We get **14** vs **24**.

On the contrary, a search for "non-printing character" has twice the results of "non-printable character".  **1,007** and **2,640** respectively.

Google returns roughly the same number of results for the searches "non-printing" and "non-printable" (quotes *included* in search).

Based on the low number of questions with these tag, it's hard to say that's compelling evidence of future use.  The text-based search, however, indicates that "non-printing" is more common on Stackoverflow.